# Why is the animation playing wierd when I check the root motion check box?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

So basically I want to make a prefab (a cat) climb a wall, I wanna do it with basic root motion animation. Since I am new with unity and is my first time doing this I decided that I need to do a little bit of testing without any complicated animations, that being said, I made a simple animation, just moving the cat prefab, in the animation clip the cat is moving one meter on the +z axis.

When I play the animation without the "Root Motion" check box checked it works just fine, but when I play it with root motion active (by the way, I checked the root motion check box and I clicked on "Generate Root Motion Curves") it plays in a different way. Instead of moving on the +z axis is moving on the -Z with a shorter distance and a shorter time as well and on the +y axis it moves a much shorter distance (I forgot to mention that I moved the prefab on the y axis as well, to simulate a very basic "jump" so to speak). I am using an animator to trigger the animation right when the game starts and the animation is set to loop.

Why does it do that and how can I fix it so the animation is played with root motion exactly like it plays without the "Root Motion" check box checked? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isnt with your animation. The issue is that Root Motion uses the animation to calculate the movement.

If your script is telling the cat to move, and root motion is telling the cat to move, there will be a conflict. When using root motion, comment out the portion of your script that is telling the player to move one meter.

This should allow unity to do its calculation and move the prefab accordingly. For an in depth explanation, see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, unfortunately that is not the problem, I don't have any script on the cat, when I said "i moved the cat 1 meter" I was referring to the fact that I moved it with an animation clip, animating it to move 1 meter on the +z axis.

Comment: I managed to resolve half of the problem. The cat prefab wasn't correctly proportionated in blender, so  I changed the scale in blender with the scale that I wanted it to be in unity without making any changes to the proportion in the unity editor. HOWEVER the z axis problem is still occurring, instead of moving on the +z axis is moving again, on the -z axis, even if the cat is animated to move on the +z axis. Why is that and again, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you have the model oriented properly in blender? In blender Z is the up axis, and in unity, Y is the up axis.